# Popup MsgBox only once after 1 iteration

Tags: vba, loops, ms-project, msgbox

I want to have popup window only to show once regardless the number of *tpred* in this code. 
How to get on one popup window  with all the examples from the loop. Now I need to confirm with Yes button each finding.

The macro is used in MS Project to trigger the task and to check if the predesessor is complete. If there is more then one predessecor, the popup appears with each predecessor.

Im very poor in VBA so will appreciate your help.

```
For Each T In ActiveSelection.Tasks

    reportingTeam = T.Text3
    RICEF = T.Text21
    UniqueID = T.UniqueID
    TaskName = T.Name
    completion = T.PercentComplete
    Duration = T.Duration / 60 & " hour/s"
    Start = DatePart("d", T.Start) & "." & DatePart("m", T.Start) & "." & DatePart("yyyy", T.Start)
    Finish = DatePart("d", T.Finish) & "." & DatePart("m", T.Finish) & "." & DatePart("yyyy", T.Finish)
    primaryres = T.Text4
    DataTeamResp = T.Text23
    recip2 = T.Text25
    reso = T.ResourceNames
    SPOC = T.Text10

    ' check if task isnt trigered?
    If completion > 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Task already triggered")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each tpred In T.PredecessorTasks

        compl = compl & tpred.PercentComplete
        prednewid = prednewid & vbNewLine & tpred.UniqueID & "<br />"
        prednnazwa = prednnazwa & vbNewLine & tpred.Name & "<br />"
        predres = predres & vbNewLine & tpred.ResourceNames & "<br />"
        predSPOC = predSPOC & vbNewLine & tpred.Text10 & "<br />"
        predcomp = predcomp & vbNewLine & tpred.PercentComplete & " %" & "<br />"

        If compl <> 100 Then

            info = info & vbNewLine & tpred.UniqueID & " -> " & tpred.Name & " -> " & tpred.PercentComplete & " %" & " -> " & tpred.ResourceNames

            If MsgBox("For the:   " & T.UniqueID & "  ->  " & T.Name & vbNewLine & "following predecessors are not complete: " & vbNewLine & info & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Do you still want to trigger this task?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then

                info = ""
                Exit Sub

            End If

        End If

    Next tpred

    T.PercentComplete = 5
    completion = T.PercentComplete / 100

Next T
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable to track whether all predecessors are complete and move the message box for incomplete predecessors ***outside*** the loop:

```
Dim AllPredsComplete As Boolean
AllPredsComplete = True

For Each tpred In T.PredecessorTasks

    prednewid = prednewid & vbNewLine & tpred.UniqueID & "<br />"
    prednnazwa = prednnazwa & vbNewLine & tpred.Name & "<br />"
    predres = predres & vbNewLine & tpred.ResourceNames & "<br />"
    predSPOC = predSPOC & vbNewLine & tpred.Text10 & "<br />"
    predcomp = predcomp & vbNewLine & tpred.PercentComplete & " %" & "<br />"

    If tpred.PercentComplete < 100 Then
        AllPredsComplete = False
        info = info & vbNewLine & tpred.UniqueID & " -> " & tpred.Name & " -> " _
            & tpred.PercentComplete & " %" & " -> " & tpred.ResourceNames
    End If

Next tpred

If Not AllPredsComplete Then

    If MsgBox("For the:   " & T.UniqueID & "  ->  " & T.Name & vbNewLine _
        & "following predecessors are not complete: " & vbNewLine & info & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & "Do you still want to trigger this task?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then

        info = ""
        Exit Sub

    End If

End If
```

Comment: Hi Rachel, 
I really appreciate your help, it works brilliant. Thank you so much!

Also didn't know I can use _ to break the line :) Everyday something new.
Regards
Jarek

Answer (score -1):

You solution is to create a custom form rather than use the built-in message box.

Making some assumptions about what you want:

- Have a simple label at the top of the tasks which says something
  along the lines of "The following tasks have predecessors which are
  not complete. Select which tasks you still want to trigger."
- Use the `For Each tpred In T.PredecessorTasks` to add a checkbox to
  your form. This could simply be a checkbox with the name of the task and the relevant predecessors as the caption.
- Within this loop, only add the tasks that meet the `If compl <> 100`
  condition.
- Once the form is built in the `For Each tpred In T.PredecessorTasks`
  loop, you must then show the form and allow the user to check/select
  each task. The form must also have a button the user can press to
  confirm their selection.
- Once the user has confirmed their selection, run through each of the
  checkboxes and process however you need to. The user may select none,
  or they may select all.

I have used some specific terms here - part of your learning journey is to find and use these terms to build your knowledge and experience. Along this journey, you will learn things like:

- How to make a custom form
- How to add controls to a collection or array
- How to process controls from a collection or array
- How to resize a form so that it looks neat when you don't initially
  know how many controls will be on the form.

In some of those steps you may encounter coding challenges - if you cannot find an answer through searching (your favourite search engine or here on Stack Exchange), then open a new question with that specific problems. Lots of people here with experience willing to help.